# Move all files with a certain extension from different subdirectories

Tags: directory, rm, extension

Is there any Linux command to move all files with a certain extension (let's say .txt) from all different subdirectory (which has subsubdirectories, subsubsubdirectories...) to another directory?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution would be with `find`:

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec mv {} /destination \;
```

You’ll want to be careful about files with the same name, though, as this will overwrite them. If you want to keep all files intact, use this:

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec mv -n {} /destination \;
```

This should do what you’re looking for.

Comment: ... or more efficiently `-exec mv -n -t /destination {} +`